# Retrieving a file from iPhone device

Tags: iphone

I'm making a game and writing save files into the document directory on the iPhone.

Is there a way for me to retrieve these files from the actual device? I know I can find the ones saved from the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plug the phone into your Mac, and open Xcode and then Xcode's Organiser window.

From there, you can select your iPhone from the device list on the left. This will show the details of your iPhone, (provisions, installed apps etc).

You should be able to see your app in the list of installed apps, with a disclosure arrow next to it ( > ). Click that and it'll expand to show a package icon with the text Application Data, and a "download arrow" icon to the right.

Click the download arrow and it'll ask you where to save the data.

The result is a folder containing the Documents, Library and tmp directories from your application.

Hope this helps.